# All reducers will be invoked when an action is dispatched?

Tags: redux

I am using combineReducers to combine all the reducers to create the store, does it mean that any action dispatched from any view will trigger all the reducers being invoked to check the action type？Is it kind of low efficiency?

Or I don't fully understand the redux design principle？

Answer (score 31):

Yes, that is correct.

However one option you have to optimize this behaviour (suggested from the Redux docs) is to use 'reselect' https://github.com/rackt/reselect

Reselect basically allows you to create memoized selectors, whereby you can say that props A depends on state B and state C, and therefore only recompute props A if state B or state C changes.

Notice that this will still trigger all of the reducers to run (and go through the switch statement to see if the action might apply to them) - I believe there is no way around this behaviour. Using reselect however means that your top level component will only receive a prop/state change if there was an actual change that affects that state, rather than triggering a change every time and making React re-render everything, even when the change had no effect because it was somewhere unrelated. (The readme in reselect explains better)

Comment: Actually I am using vue.js with redux, thanks for your suggestion all the same.

Comment: You are welcome :) but regardless, although all reducers are called, what really happens is that the switch statements are checked, and only the reducer that handles that action will do some work, all others don't do anything, so it really isn't a performance issue. It is worth mentioning that modern JS optimise big switch statements into a jump table with O(1) access time, so you don't need to worry about evaluating large switch statements either in reducers, even if many times the action doesn't match any conditions.

Comment: An action observer pattern inside reducer would have better instead of doing it through switch, it is perfect example of observer pattern

Comment: It is worth noting that since all reducers are called, if two reducers handle the same action,then both will be invoked

Answer (score 7):

Yes - all the reducers will get called when you dispatch the action. You will get one nice side effect to it. Because every reducer returns default state if the action isn't found you get your initial state set up with a single action.

It could be beneficial, although I haven't tried it yet, to have single action affecting multiple reducers aka changing the state in two different part of the store.

When you add reselect to it as @luanped suggested you can get a lot of sick results!

My current stack is:

- Redux for state, actions management
- Reselect for data transformation layer
- React for views

Adding reselect to the work flow and making it work alongside reducers was the best thing that happened to me last week.

Comment: `a lot of sick results` sounds opposite to `best thing that happened to me`, so are you suggesting to use `reselect`?

Comment: heheh sick as wicked or twisted === good but unexpected.... and yes reselect is a very powerful addition to the work flow. The moment you realize that your selector can return momoized functions that depend on your state you are at home:)

Comment: @Kocur4d What do you mean `every reducer returns default state if the action isn't found you get your initial state setup with a single action` ?

Comment: @Reza all your reducers have `default: return state` in the switch statement. When you dispatch your action `dispatch({type: 'i_am_action', ...})` this action will be seen by **all** the reducers not only the one that define this action in a case statement. So if you use initial state wisely you will get the starting desired shape of your application with only a single action.

Comment: @Kocur4d correct me if i'm wrong `default: return state` that doesn't mean it returns always initial state, if you changed your state, then from next time you will get the changed state as default. So it always returns my current sate for any reducer.

Comment: @Reza you are correct, `default: return state` always returns the current state. My explanation could be little bit confusing as I was focusing on the initial load of the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore actions of specific reducer by using https://github.com/omnidan/redux-ignore

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
// redux-ignore higher-order reducer
import { ignoreActions } from 'redux-ignore'
 combineReducers({
  counter: ignoreActions(counter, [INCREMENT_COUNTER])
});
```

Also read about performance on official site 
https://redux.js.org/faq/performance/#wont-calling-all-my-reducers-for-each-action-be-slow