# React Native with Redux - inefficient?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm getting into react native and redux, and as far as I understand *all* reducers are invoked upon a triggered event that changes state, regardless of whether it is tied to the specific action triggered. So my question is... isn't this highly inefficient? For example, in responding to a touch event, without redux you have one callback responding to the event. However, with redux, every reducer in your app is invoked even if that action/state has nothing to do with the event in question. How is this good?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All reducers will be invoked when an action is dispatched?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590579/all-reducers-will-be-invoked-when-an-action-is-dispatched)

Answer (score 0):

One way to optimize your redux store(s) is to to use selectors with a library such as [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) as documented [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) in the Redux docs.